# CakePHP: login fails following a specific set of steps

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to set up a simple login system, but I'm having a particular problem that I can't solve. I have the following pages that perform self-explanatory actions. They are bookmarked for easy access.

```
cake/ (home page; must be logged in)
cake/login (must be logged in)
cake/logout (must be logged in)
cake/add (must be logged in)
```

All seems to work except when I preform the following sequence of actions:

```
1. log in
2. go to cake/logout to log out (login works immediately after this step)
3. go to cake/logout again immediately
4. attempt to log in but cake/login is just re-displayed and I'm not logged in
5. attempt to log in again and it is successful
```

I have noticed that `$this->Session->flash('auth')` is FALSE after step 3 but it is not false after 4. I tried destroying the session before or after logging out with no effect. Any ideas?

My code bits are below:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add');
}   
public function add() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('User created!');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'login'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Please correct the errors');
        }
    }
}   
public function login() {
}   
public function logout() {  
    $this->Session->destroy(); // makes no difference
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout()); // redirected to login() by default
}   
}

class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array('Auth', 'Session');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are being redirected to the logout screen after your login.
When you go to a page you don't have access to (like the logout screen), you are redirected to login.
Once you enter name and password, you are taken back to your original request.
When that original request happens to be the logout page, logout occurs and you are sent back to the login.